# How do I install the latest ATI Catalyst Video Drivers in Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal?

Tags: ati, fglrx, 12.10, catalyst

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers)

I've found instructions, including [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers) for 12.04, but nothing for 12.10. Can someone help?

Comment: We'll just work on updating that master question for 12.10 too.